# Rendering text inside gtkglext widget - from glut to pango

Tags: opengl, gtk, glut, pango

I'm in the process of constructing a user interface for my C/C++ simulation application using gtk+, and moving away from command-line control. I've used gtkglext to embed my OpenGL rendering of the simulation to reside inside a widget. Initially I used OpenGL + GLUT to do everything, but since constructing the UI and moving to gtkglext I'm having to supplant GLUT entirely.

The way I used to render text 'inside' the OpenGL rendering window was to use glutStrokeCharacter. Should I now use Pango instead? The important thing is to be able to rotate and scale the text in the same way as the rest of the simulation data -- for labeling axes, drawing scales, etc.

I've been looking at the font-pangoft2.c example. Any further references would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you need to "supplant GLUT entirely"? You should be able to still use glutStrokeCharacter even though the OpenGL context is created by gtkglext.

From the sound of it you won't have a large amount of text. One option may be to use GtkLabel to draw to a GdkPixmap, then upload the pixmap as an OpenGL texture.